Why is my PHP script throwing a "Mismatched field count" error when adding dynamic rows in an accounting journal entry?
I am developing an accounting system where users can add journal entries with dynamic rows for account, debtor, creditor, description, and acc_serial. However, when I add a new dynamic row and submit the form, the script throws an error:

An error occurred while processing data. Please try again.

This issue seems to arise because the arrays in the POST request (account, debtor, creditor, description, and acc_serial) have mismatched counts.
What I've tried:
PHP server-side validation
I added a validation step to ensure that all arrays (account, debtor, creditor, description, and acc_serial) have the same count:
if (count($_POST['account']) !== count($_POST['debtor']) || 
    count($_POST['account']) !== count($_POST['creditor']) || 
    count($_POST['account']) !== count($_POST['description']) || 
    count($_POST['account']) !== count($_POST['acc_serial'])) {
    
    echo '<script>toastr.error("Mismatched field count. Please verify the data.");</script>';
    exit;
}


This triggers the error message when the counts don't match.
Debugging POST data
I used var_dump($_POST) to inspect the submitted data. Here's the output for a problematic request:
 array (size=15)
  'date' => string '2024-12-09' (length=10)
  'entry_num' => string 'JE-0001' (length=7)
  'descrip' => string '6565' (length=4)
  'company' => string 'sahat' (length=5)
  'auth_token' => string '2582f394f3dab3ac3f139d1f7e715d6181ad182a' (length=40)
  'serial' => string '3CWZE7B8ZSVIO71Q440HT6HWX1RWKY3B8EL' (length=35)
  'j_type' => string 'Manual Entry' (length=15)
  'account' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'd59f127d86' (length=10)
      1 => string 'd5a05ca920' (length=10)
      2 => string 'd59fb74cb8' (length=10)
  'debtor' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '2000' (length=4)
      1 => string '0' (length=1)
  'creditor' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => string '1000' (length=4)
  'description' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'General Expense' (length=19)
      1 => string 'General Expense' (length=19)
  'acc_serial' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'd59f127d86' (length=10)
      1 => string 'd59fb74cb8' (length=10)


Account has 3 items, while debtor, creditor, description, and acc_serial have only 2 items.
PHP loop for processing rows
foreach ($_POST['account'] as $index => $value) {
    if (isset($_POST['account'][$index], $_POST['debtor'][$index], $_POST['creditor'][$index], $_POST['description'][$index], $_POST['acc_serial'][$index])) {
        $account = $_POST['account'][$index];
        $debtor = $_POST['debtor'][$index];
        $creditor = $_POST['creditor'][$index];
        $description = $_POST['description'][$index];
        $acc_serial = $_POST['acc_serial'][$index];
        
        if (empty($account) || empty($description) || empty($acc_serial) || $debtor === "" || $creditor === "") {
            echo '<script>toastr.error("Please fill all fields in row ' . ($index + 1) . '");</script>';
            exit;
        }

        if (!is_numeric($debtor) || !is_numeric($creditor)) {
            echo '<script>toastr.error("Debtor and Creditor must be numeric in row ' . ($index + 1) . '");</script>';
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        echo '<script>toastr.error("An error occurred while processing data. Please try again.");</script>';
        exit;
    }
}

HTML structure for dynamic rows
<table class="table" id="dynamicAddRemove">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Account</th>
            <th>Debtor</th>
            <th>Creditor</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control select_acount" name="account[]" required>
                    <option value="d59f127d86">Sample Account 1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="debtor[]" class="form-control debtor" required></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="creditor[]" class="form-control creditor" required></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control" required></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="acc_serial[]" value="d59f127d86" class="form-control acc_serial" required></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
            <td><button type="button" id="add-btn" class="btn btn-success">Add Row</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

JavaScript for adding dynamic rows:
$("#add-btn").click(function() {
    let i = $("#dynamicAddRemove tbody tr").length;
    
    $("#dynamicAddRemove").append('<tr>' +
        '<td><select class="form-control select_acount" name="account[]" required></select></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="debtor[]" class="form-control debtor" required></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="creditor[]" class="form-control creditor" required></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control" required></td>' +
        '<td><input type="hidden" name="acc_serial[]" class="form-control acc_serial" required></td>' +
        '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button></td>' +
    '</tr>');
});

What could cause this mismatch in field counts when adding dynamic rows?
How can I debug or fix this issue to ensure all fields are submitted correctly?

You should be appending to $("#dynamicAddRemove tbody"). What is the i variable for?

But I can't see any reason for the mismatch. Are you sending the form data using normal form submission, or AJAX?

Use the Elements viewer in DevTools to make sure that all the input fields are inside the <form>.

Which row is missing from the  POST data? Is it the initial static row, or one of the dynamically-added rows?
